# Need Multiprocessing Pandas dataframe output of list returned from function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiprocessing

I am trying to return the results of a multiprocessing execution in a Pandas DataFrame where I can see the value in NICE Dataframe like below as alternate separate Grid in Jupyternotebook.

```
import pandas as pd
import json

    def f1():
        t = [{"arrival_date": "2019-12-01", "asof_date": "2019-08-01"}, {"arrival_date": "2019-12-01", "asof_date": "2019-08-01"}]
        print (type (dump))
        df = pd.DataFrame(dump)
        return  pd.DataFrame(t)

    f1()
```

However when I am trying to achieve same things with multiprocessing I am not getting dataframe printed with nice grid . It seems I am bound to print the return value(with python print statement) which is splitting up the columns while printing and I have 30 rows to print .

Here is what I was trying to use Shared variable to communicate and finally just call 'df' to print the nice alternate separate output I get below error : 
I have objective to print as 'df' and not print(df) also ..is that not possible ? Not sure why it is returning in first example .

```
import multiprocessing

def f1(i,t):
    t = [{"arrival_date": "2019-12-01", "asof_date": "2019-08-01"}, {"arrival_date": "2019-12-01", "asof_date": "2019-08-01"}]
    return  t

for i in range(2):
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    t = manager.list() 
    t_sub = multiprocessing.Process(target=f1, args=(i,t))
    t_sub.start()
    t_sub.join()
df = pd.DataFrame(t)
df
```

Also for below it is not returning the dataframe from multiprocessing call :

```
import multiprocessing

def f1(i,t):
    t = [{"arrival_date": "2019-12-01", "asof_date": "2019-08-01"}, {"arrival_date": "2019-12-01", "asof_date": "2019-08-01"}]
    return  pd.DataFrame(t)

for i in range(2):
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    t = manager.list() 
    t_sub = multiprocessing.Process(target=f1, args=(i,t))
    t_sub.start()
    t_sub.join()
```

Comment: I guess I got my problem solved with display(df) rather print(df) for Panda's dataframe Jupyternotebook high rich display .